# Как это объяснить? Типы данных

Tags: javascript

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это объяснить?
и false и undefined являются ложными типами, но в нестрогом сравнении они не равны друг другу(

Comment: когда используется не строгое сравнение [оба значения должны иметь значения приводымие в true или false](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-11.9.3), но [undefined](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-8.1) и [null](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-8.2) имеют только одно значение - это undefined и null, соответственно, и такое сравнение всегда будет давать false

Comment: Но, они двоем приводятся к false, скриншот приложил. false  == false ведь = true

Comment: [они не приводятся](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-11.4.9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Так решили авторы JavaScript ¯\_(ツ)_/¯**

А вот полная табличка истинности сравнений:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*// источник https://algassert.com/visualization/2014/03/27/Better-JS-Equality-Table.html*

Comment: Похоже разрабы JS стремились нарисовать стрелочку в приведении типов))

Answer (score 2):

При нестрогом сравнении null и  undefined равны друг другу и не равны никаким другим значениям. Это специальное правило языка. Соответственно они не могут быть равны false.

При строгом, они не равны друг другу, так как это разные типы данных.